# Создание цели Google Analytics при появлении класса.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вся проблема в том, что я плохо знаю js и не могу понять как реализовать свою задумку. Есть форма, которая после успешной заявки создает себе класс типа - formsuccess. Я хочу повесить функцию на кнопку submit чтобы вызвать функцию и проверить появился ли класс formsucces если да, то вызвать функцию цели. 
ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'succes'); return true;

Я не понимаю как вызвать функцию просто при поиске класса.

Не могу найти похожую ситуацию и материал как правильно создать и вызвать такую функцию. Ну и желательно сделать это запуск функцию с интервалом, чтобы форма успела получить статус.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Упростил одну из своих функций (если правильно понял задачу):

```
function submitForm(){
    $("form.form:not(.no-ajax)").submit(function(){
        var form=$(this);

        $.ajax({
            method:"post",
            url:form.attr("action")+"&ajax",
            data:form.serialize(),
            cache:false,
            error:function(){
                //show some error
            },
            success:function(result){
                form.addClass("formsuccess");
                ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'succes');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
}
```

Смысл в том, что после успешной отправки формы делаем что хотим дальше. Попробуйте такую реализацию. Либо в Вашем случае вызывайте `ga()` сразу после добавления класса к Вашей форме.

Comment: Да, а вот как вызвать функцию сразу после добавления класса?)

Comment: В моем примере вызов отслеживания цели аналитики идет сразу после добавления класса, Вы можете поступить аналогично

Comment: Просто отлично. Пришлось разобраться в этом вопросе детальнее, я раньше не работал с Ajax) Как оказалось тут и классы не нужны, просто отдаю цель если результат ок. Спасибо!